# How can I create an executable for MySQL+Python in Linux?

Tags: python, mysql

I have python code and it uses a MySQL database. How can I create a Linux executable wrapping both? The python code depends on some shared objects as well. Those need to be included in the executable file as well.

Comment: look forward to this answer myself. Should have bookmarked it once

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different avenues you can take, it depends on your needs.

**Debian/RPM Packging**

This method involves creating a linux package that can be installed using the package manager.

Pros: It can bring in mysql and external libs, well supported, comes with applications for handling packages on most Linux systems (Muon, synaptics, ubuntu software manager), Updates via repositories if used, newbie friendly

Cons: Specific to a package manager standard (yum/apt), requires handling more than just the python code, *nix only (no windows), requires hosting the file somewhere or repository access

**Github/VCS and an Executable Script**

This method involves asking the user to checkout a plain git repo with some scripts they can run to do your work.

Pros: Easy to deploy and update, Developer Friendly
Cons: No dependency checking unless you build it yourself, requires `git` or other control verison software to be installed, less user friendly

**Pip/Setuptools**

This method involves creating a (generally) python-only package.

Pros: Easy to package and distribute to multiple platforms using PyPi (https://pypi.python.org/pypi), can be installed into a virtual environment

Cons: Doesn't handle MySQL or external libs unless they exist in PyPi

**Self Extracting Archive**

http://xmodulo.com/how-to-create-a-self-extracting-archive-or-installer-in-linux.html

Pros: Easy, smaller size

Cons: No dependency checking, requires hosting the file somewhere

---

I'd recommend using Pip/Setuptools and telling people to have mysql and any other dependencies installed that you cannot bring in yourself. (There's also mariaDB which is compatible with mysql, you may not want to force one over the other). I'd think about including a configuration file (using `configparser`) so they can manage the db themselves. It reduces the burden on yourself and provides an excellent way to update your software securely. It also opens up the possibility to use other databases if you use an ORM like SqlAlchemy.